# How can I change the colour of a Button without changing its size?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm quite new to android development and I am having a problem changing the colour of my buttons.

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/SignUp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SignIn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />
```

This is the button I'm having trouble with. I've changed the background colour but it changes the size of my button.

[image]

Just for reference the left button is what I would like my button to look like but after changing the colour the right button is what I get.

I've had a quick look to try find a solution but what I've found just tells me to change the background colour which I've already done.

So how can I get it looking like the left button? I'm assuming its something to do with the drawables, but I honestly have no idea what I'm looking for. Any guides or anything to point me in the right direction would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide both buttons code

Comment: you need to show the other button code too

Comment: Sorry, done! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple answer, use `backgroundTint` insted `background`
This code will work:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/SignIn"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:backgroundTint="#00ff00"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sign In"
android:textColor="#ff0000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The background attribute can be more than just a color. You're replacing the default image with a solid color.  Options are to make your own image, or adjust the height and width attributes.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Style

Comment: Thanks, wish I could accept two answers that guide has given me a better understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your buttons into a LinearLayout view which orientation is horizaional,then set buttons' weight is 1,width is 0dp,linearLayout's height is 40dp.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is replacing an image background with a solid color. You should use styles instead.

Please try this style

```
<style name="SpecialButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
   <item name="colorButtonNormal">#00ff00</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

in your styles.xml and

```
<style name="SpecialButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
   <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#00ff00</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

in your v21/styles.xml and

and apply this style to the button. Please comment if this worked for you, as I have not tested it myself.